# How can I detect video duration inside the iframe via jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

Hello I'm trying to do an chrome extension,
 my main purpose is detect videos on the page, and check if user watch 80% of video, some sites using iframe for videos openload, king, vk, mail.ru etc.
The main question is, am I supposed to write a specific function for every source or can I detect videos with simple tricks?
Many of sources using sort of hashing or whatever for security reasons, I can't find an specific dom element with jquery.

example site html:

```
<iframe id="episode_player" src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=264230257263260272277221239235213255194271217261258&amp;autoplay=no" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="495" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

my plugin:

```
var iframeR = $("iframe#episode_player").contents().find("video").get(0);
console.log(iframeR);
```

returns undefined.

for sources who use object tag, I tried this

```
var zazi = $("iframe#episode_player").contents().find("object").length;
console.log(zazi);
```

it returns 0

any idea, which can help me to find a way?

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly, you can simply use Javascript for this:
[W3Schools rocks](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp)

If not, correct me!

Comment: thank you, I have no problem with selecting video elements inside the page except iframes, and this iframes can have very different classes in video tags, when I tried to select all with directly video element, I can't get it. My main purpose is access video element inside the iframe